# "The afternoon tea" vs "afternoon tea"

Tags: difference, definite-article, british-english, zero-article

1) Which is correct:

> A) At weekends, **afternoon tea** is a special occasion.
>
> B) At weekends, **the afternoon tea** is a special occasion.

2) Should I say "at the weekends"?

Comment: You don't need the articles, but I can't explain why. Your first version is correct.

Comment: There is a similar discussion [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75466/at-on-the-weekends).

Answer (score 1):

1) "At weekends, afternoon tea is a special occasion."

You are talking about "afternoon tea" in general, so no "the" is needed.

2) Meanwhile, both "at weekends" and "at the weekend" are acceptable in British English. In American English, it would be "on weekends" and "on the weekend(s)."

Source: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75466/at-on-the-weekends

Comment: As I understood from your link that "at the weekends" is not acceptable. Only at weekends or at the weekend

Comment: This particular case, yes, describes a general tradition that the British enjoy "at the weekend" and "the" is not necessary.  But this may not be true for *all* general cases.  For example "At our country club, **the** afternoon tea is a special occasion" used to distinguish this particular event from other, similar events.